# ChartJs functional component does not refresh even when forceUpdate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I have a chartjs graph that I embed in another component.
When this parent component mounts, I load data via a api call, and the expectation is that the graph rerenders with the right data.

Here is the code:

```
type Props = {
    readonly user_id: number;
}

type State = {
    readonly payload: Array<any>,
    readonly chartData: Array<number>
}

export default class extends React.Component<Props, State> {
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        payload: payload,
        chartData: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
}

componentDidMount = (): void => {
    axios.get(`https://heretheexamplesite.com/api/getchart/${this.props.user_id}`, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(res => {
        if (res.data['values']) {
            this.setState({ payload: res.data['values'] });
            this.setState({ chartData: [
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p1'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p2'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p3'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p4'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p5'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p6'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p7'],
                res.data['values'][0]['_source']['p8']
            ] });
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log('Force Update');
        this.forceUpdate();
    })
}

render = (): JSX.Element => {
    return <div>
         <MyChart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
    </div>
```

However MyChart does not re render when setting state. Here is the code for MyChart:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js";


type Props = {
  chartData: Array<any>
}

const MyChart = ({ chartData }: Props) => {
    const barChartData: Chart.ChartData = {
      labels: ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8"],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: "#f6c500",
        data: chartData,
      },
    ],
};
const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current?.getContext("2d");
    if (ctx) {
        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "radar",
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,                    
                ticks: {
                    display: false,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 100,
                    maxTicksLimit: 6
                }
            }
        },
    });
  }
}, []);
return (
    <div className="self-center w-1/2">
        <div className="overflow-hidden">
            <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyChart ;
```

I verified the value of barChart and the right values are stored, buyt setState does not rerender the chart.
I tried `forceUpdate` as seen above, but no results either.

What is missing to make the component rerender?

Answer (score 1):

When adding new data to the chart, or in your case when the initial data is ready, you will have to call the update methode on the chart itself. So instead of only calling `new Chart` you will have to put it into a variable and call `.update()` on it when the data changes

Comment: Thanks, that indeed seems to be what I miss. But how do I know if this is a first render or not?

Comment: when you call new Chart it automatically renders the chart with the data it currently has so the place where you call that is the inital render

Comment: hmmm yes that I get, but to force the update I need to add this in the chart .tsx, not in the parent component, should I put the Chart object as a prop?

Comment: Not that familliar with react, but I think if you make a variable at the same level as your canvasRef for your chart and put it in there when you make it. Then you will have to monitor for prop changes and if that happens you call the update on it